# geoserver and its layer is pointing(base url) to other server(hosting server) not my domain url

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext

1. i am using Geoserver 2.4.4.my geoserver url is http://links-map.com/geoserver/web/ but when i click to loging button of geoserver its url is changed http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au:8080/geoserver/web/ means after pressing the loging button geosver pointing to my hosting server url i.e http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au/

2.second issue is on layer preview when i see the the source path of layer by inspect element i fount the layer is also pointing to  my server url(http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au/) not my domain url(http://links-map.com/).

why my geoserver is pointing to my hosting server(http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au/)
 i am using dedicated server Centos 6.4  which url is http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au/ 
 and Apache tomcat  server 7.0.42

i want my geosver on my domain path( http://links-map.com/geoserver/web/) all its thing layer preview ,other on the same url (http://links-map.com). not my hosting server url .

So please any body can suggest me where i can fix this problem how can i set GeoServer on http://links-map.com/

I am giving  the screen shot  url of this please see the screen shot http://links-map.com/error.png

Please suggest me. 
        Thanks

Comment: It is hard to see how ArcGIS for Desktop which you have as a tag comes into this Question.  Also, you seem to be asking more than one question so I think you should edit it to focus on whichever one is the most important to you.

Comment: Both question has same issue and same problem.when i display layer as open layer preview. i found that the source path is my hosting server url.that is(http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au).the path should be (links-map.com)

Comment: This looks like a DNS or proxy issue, not a GeoServer issue. How are you routing your site name to the host?

Comment: My site name is http://links-map.com/ and Geoserver path is http://links-map.com/geoserver.But when i click on login button of geoserver it redirect to my hosting server url http://vmx15978.hosting24.com.au:8080/geoserver/ so where can i set Proxy or DNS setting to fix this

Comment: Looks like your DNS authority is sedoparking.com. If you do not already have a handle on the DNS, then that complicates things quite a bit.  Proxy is something you will have to install and configure on your server.  See if you can obtain your DNS configuration.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, go to the Global Settings page in the GeoServer configuration UI. There you enter http://links-map.com/geoserver/ in the "Proxy Base URL" field.

Comment: Are there more posibilities what can cause this Problem? I am experiencing the same behaviour (Geoserver Admin Interface is pointing to an "old" URL while Proxy Base URL is set correctly). Where does the Admin UI get this URL from?